# c bubblesort a link list

Tags: c, bubble-sort

trying to get a function to run that will bubble sort a link list from smallest to largest number. I don't want the data to be moved around in the link list instead have the pointers be pointing elsewhere in case each link needs to hold a lot of data.

In each link I have a INT arrivalTime field that will house a integer value. THis number determines where the link should be in the list.

My program seems to hang at the moment, I'd appreciate if anyone could fix it up, Thanks

bubble sort function

```
void bubbleSort(struct order *start)
{
  int swapped, i;
  processData *current = start;
  processData *temp;
  struct order *lptr = NULL;

  /* Checking for empty list */
   if (current == NULL)
    printf("null \n");


  do
    {
      swapped = 0;
      current = start;

      while (current->next != lptr)
        {
      if (current->arrivalTime > current->next->arrivalTime)
            {
          temp = current;
          current = current->next;
          current->next = temp;
          swapped = 1;
            }
      current = current->next;
        }
      lptr = current;
    }
    while (swapped);
}
```

structure of link list

```
struct order 
{
  int name;
  int arrivalTime;
  int quanta;
  struct order * next;
};
typedef struct order processData;
```

Comment: what does the debugger say?

Comment: Kindly use a debugger like `gdb` and try to step through the program.

Comment: `void bubbleSort(struct order *start)` : this Interface cannnot swap first element.

Comment: i've read up on the internet you can only change data elements of a link list and not the pointers with bubble sort?

Comment: You can perform a swap either by updating the `next` pointers or by swapping the data. If you choose to swap data, you may want to define the `list` structure separately from the `data` structure, so that the `list` structure has a pointer to the `data` structure.

Comment: If you use a double pointer (pointer to pointer to node), that is set to &start or &(node->next), then special code to handle updating start will not be needed. If you have node **ppnode = &start, then to advance ppnode, you use ppnode = &((*ppnode)->next);

Comment: As a somewhat faster alternative to bubble sort, you could simply scan the list to find the pointer to the node with the largest value, then remove that node from the original list and insert it into the front of a new, initially empty list. Repeat this process until the original list is empty, and the new list contains all the nodes (in sorted order). For a large list, using a merge oriented sort would be much faster, but that's a totally different approach.

Answer (score 0):

Swapping two adjacent items in a singly-linked-list requires that you change three `next` pointers.

If the order is `A --> B --> C --> D` and you swap `B` with `C` to get `A --> C --> B --> D` then

`A->next` needs to point to `C` instead of `B`
`B->next` needs to point to `D` instead of `C`
`C->next` needs to point to `B` instead of `D`

Comment: lets say using your example i want to swap a & b around.
if im currently at link A:
id store the current address of a,b,c in temp variables.
then using current->next-> assign that to the address of A and the current address of a id point assign to the address of C

Comment: @Bobski I'm not sure I understand. If you're at position `A`, you can't swap `A` and `B` without backing up and figuring out what points to `A`. If `A` is the very first item in the list, then presumably `start` points to `A`, and that causes the problem that BLUEPIXY commented on. To change what `start` points to, you need to pass `start` as a pointer-to-a-pointer, i.e. `bubbleSort(struct order **start)`

Comment: @rcgldr In context, adjacent is implied, but I agree that I should have been explicit, thanks.

Comment: Although this doesn't occur with bubble sort, if swapping two non-adjacent items, you change four next pointers. For example, A --> B --> C --> D -->E, and you swap B and D. A->next points to D instead of B. B->next points to E instead of C. C->next points to B instead of D. D->next points to B instead of E. If you keep track of what points to B and D, then if you swap X->B with Y->D, then swap B->next with D->next, the logic works with adjacent or non-adjacent items. Normally X and Y will be double pointers, to start of list and/or items in the list.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very slow thing you're trying to do - see this paper on [comparing ways to sort a linked list](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=C168E4B02EED9EFC56FBCB7972C3A955?doi=10.1.1.31.9981&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

Currently, your algorithm will never terminate because in your while loop, you set `lptr = current`, but then test whether `current->next == lptr`.  This will never return true unless one of your list members points to itself.

If you do have a definite use case to bubble sort the linked list, consider this:  The purpose of a linked list is that you access it by working sequentially from the list head to the item you want.  If your initial list head is not the smallest or the largest and you're only changing pointers, you need to keep track of where the head of the list is.

I did think of a way to do it loosely based on yours, see below.  Sorry it's a bit messy - I'm not a C expert (hope the memory allocation is OK...) and I'm sure there are optimisations.  In particular I'm sure there are better ways to pass the headOfList pointer back to the `main` algorithm.  I've tested it for a number of 100 member lists of structs with some negative numbers.  I've left the code to generate them with random arrival times in `main()` so you can just paste this in where your old code was and run it.

```
processData *bubbleSort(processData *start)
{
  int swapped;
  processData *current = start;
  processData *lheadptr = start;
  processData *previous = NULL;
  processData *oldPrevButBigger;
  processData *oldAfterThisPair;

  /* Checking for empty list */
   if (current == NULL)
   {
     printf("null \n");
     return NULL;
   }

  do
    {
      swapped = 0;
      current = lheadptr;
      previous = NULL;

      while (current->next) //Stop when current->next is null (i.e. end of list)
        {
          if (current->arrivalTime > current->next->arrivalTime)
            {
              oldPrevButBigger = current;
              oldAfterThisPair = current->next->next;
              current = current->next;
              current->next = oldPrevButBigger;
              current->next->next = oldAfterThisPair;

              if (!previous)
                {
                   //If no previous, this was the head of the list, so need to update
                   lheadptr = current;
                }
              else
                {
                   // If there is a "previous", then we're not at head of list, so need
                   // to update that pointer too
                   previous->next = current;
                }
              swapped = 1;
            }
          previous = current;
          current = current->next;
        }
    }
    while (swapped);

    return lheadptr;
}


int main()
{


   srand(time(NULL));
   int NUM = 100;

   processData* pointToLast = NULL;
   int i;
   processData orders[NUM];  

   //Generate a list with random arrival times (last member of the list generated first
   for (i = 0; i < NUM; i++ )
     {
           orders[i].name = i;
           orders[i].arrivalTime = rand()-1000000000;
           orders[i].quanta = 500;
           orders[i].next = pointToLast;
       pointToLast = &orders[i];
    }


   printf("List before\n");
   printf("===========\n"); 
   for (i=0; i < NUM; i++)
   {
             printf("%i;%i;%i\n", pointToLast->name, pointToLast->arrivalTime, pointToLast->quanta);
        pointToLast = pointToLast->next;
   }

   processData* newListHead = bubbleSort(&orders[NUM-1]);  

   printf("List after\n");
   printf("===========\n"); 
   for (i=0; i < NUM; i++)
   {
             printf("%i;%i;%i\n", newListHead->name, newListHead->arrivalTime, newListHead->quanta);
        newListHead = newListHead->next;
   }


    return 0;
}
```